# Bitbucket Pipeline sass

Tags: sass, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a simple app that uses sass that I'm trying to set up with pipelines
Currently its failing because sass command can't be found.
I'm guessing I need to run gem install sass? but how can I add this to my pipeline config? Currently it looks like this:

```
image: node:7.4.0
pipelines:
default:
- step:
    script:
    - npm install
    - npm install -g grunt
    - npm install -g grunt-cli
    - grunt prod
    - ./heroku-deploy.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using a ruby-node image, which gives access to gem install

```
image: starefossen/ruby-node:2-5
```